# Radio buttons not adding value to label

Tags: c#, asp.net

im trying to add values up and submit to a label once a radio button is selected. Its not doing it at all.

any ideas?

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:Label ID="CountTest" runat="server" Text="CountTester"></asp:Label>
 <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" />
```

**C#**

```
        int Total = 2 ;

        CountTest.Text = Convert.ToString(Total);


        if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            Total = Total + 1;
        }

        else if (radio2.Checked == true)
        {
            Total = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Where do you assign `Total` to the label's text? What is wrong at all? It's not doing it, what happens instead?

Comment: Also use `if(RadioButton1.Checked)` instead of `if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)` for the love of George Boole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RadioButtonList:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Text="+1"  Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="0"  Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

notice -> `AutoPostBack="True"`

and the server side:

```
protected void RadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Total = 2;

        if (RadioButtonList.Items[0].Selected)
        {
            Total++;
        }
        if (RadioButtonList.Items[1].Selected)
        {
            Total = 0;
        }

        Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Total);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure, that you assign `Total` value after your counting logic, like this:

```
    ......
    if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        Total = Total + 1;
    }

    else if (radio2.Checked == true)
    {
        Total = 0;
    }

    CountTest.Text = Convert.ToString(Total);   <----- this
```

And alse be sure, that after this logic you have a PostBack.

Comment: Unsure on post backs. Can you explain? please.

Comment: When you click on RadioButton your counting logic should execute and then submitted to the server and after that your page will be refreshed. That is a PostBack. You can find example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Asp-Control/RadiobuttonautopostbackC.htm)